# runtime exceptions and error Catch or Specify Requirement

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I was reading about [exceptions in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html)

and i came across this

> Checked exceptions are subject to the Catch or Specify Requirement. All exceptions are checked exceptions, except for those indicated by Error, `RuntimeException`, and their subclasses.

Which i don't understand. Could someone please tell me what it means ?

Answer (score 4):

> Checked exceptions are subject to the Catch or Specify Requirement.
>   All exceptions are checked exceptions, except for those indicated by
>   Error, RuntimeException, and their subclasses.

It says all the exceptions needs to be handled either by catching them

```
try{
  call();
}catch(SomeException ex){
 //handling
}
```

or by throwing back

public void caller() throws SomeException{
      call();
    }

`call();` method is declared to throw `SomeException`

public void caller(){
      call();
    }

This will not compile,

There are `RuntimeException` which are unchecked, you don't need to handle them, they are mainly unexpected ones (some of them are errors) so we don't have to forcibly handle them

---

**See Also**

- [Checked vs Unchecked exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639432/checked-vs-unchecked-exception)
- [When to choose checked and unchecked exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578/when-to-choose-checked-and-unchecked-exceptions)
- [Isn't an unchecked exception that is caught in a try block a checked exception in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051728/isnt-an-unchecked-exception-that-is-caught-in-a-try-block-a-checked-exception-i)